# How to get rid of let using before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to get rid of `let!` - to do so I want to move it to the `before` method (it has to be created before everything else).

```
describe AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker do
  include_context 'with admin_user form'

  subject(:delete_worker) { described_class.new.perform }

  let!(:admin_panel_log1) do
    create :admin_panel_log,
           new_data: admin_user_form,
           created_at: created_at
  end
  let!(:admin_panel_log2) do
    create :admin_panel_log,
           new_data: admin_user_form,
           created_at: 2.days.ago
  end
  let(:created_at) { 2.years.ago }

  context 'when admin log is outdated' do
    it 'delete only outdated data' do
      expect { delete_worker }.to change(AdminPanelLog, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
```

I want to do something like this

```
  before { admin_panel_log1 }
  before { admin_panel_log2 }
```

but how to do it in one line?

Comment: Where is the `let!` you want to get rid of?

Comment: @mrzasa sorry, question updated

Comment: If you want one-liner really badly, you can do `admin_panel_log1; admin_panel_log2`, but frankly, I don't see any point in doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to change your code to this:

```
describe AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker do
  include_context 'with admin_user form'

  subject(:delete_worker) { described_class.new.perform }

  let(:admin_panel_log1) {
    create :admin_panel_log, new_data: admin_user_form, created_at: 2.years.ago
  }
  let(:admin_panel_log2) {
    create :admin_panel_log, new_data: admin_user_form, created_at: 2.days.ago
  }

  before do
    admin_panel_log1
    admin_panel_log2
  end

  context 'when admin log is outdated' do
    it 'delete only outdated data' do
      expect { delete_worker }.to change(AdminPanelLog, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```